# form action not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have the following code form for tracking different items but the closing  tag appears in red and cant make the submit work. I cant see what i have missed and how to make it work, if someone can point me in the right direction, i`d appreciate.
Thanks alot!

```
<form action='http://tm4w.mtiorg.com/trace/external_bill_viewer.msw' method='post' name='frmExternalTrace' target='_blank'> 
    <strong>Quick Trace</strong>: 
        <select name='trace_type' id='trace_type' >
            <option value="BPTRACE" >Shipper's Bill of Lading</option>
            <option value="~PTLORDER" > Website's Bill Number</option>
            <option value="PPTRACE">Purchase Order </option>
            <option value="5PTRACE">Cost Object Number</option>
        </select> 
<input name='search_value' id='search_value' type='text' value=''>    
<input name='Submit' type='button' value='Submit' onclick='return external_trace_submit()'>
</form>
```

Comment: "onclick='return external_trace_submit() " why do you have return in there? Also if you are calling a javascript function when clicking submit.. is that how you are posting? or are you posting via the action url? you don't need both. Unless the on click has nothing to do with posting data.

Comment: just posting the action via the url. ignore the onclick, even if i delete it, the search still wont work...

Comment: have you tried <input ... blah blah /> instead of <input... blah blah >. Some old browsers do not accept the second way.

Comment: If you're using any javascript listener to the onsubmit, it has to return "true" so the form is submitted. I can't see what's wrong with you code as it is

Answer (score 3):

You need to close your input tags, that will fix the red (change the last > to /> ).

Then change the input type on your submit button to 'submit'.

```
<input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Submit' onclick='return external_trace_submit()' />
```

Comment: great, love you bro. changing type 'submit' from 'button' fixed it, overlooked it.